# I'm working on a project with infrared light and I need materials that are transparent to IR light

Tags: material-science, infrared-radiation

I'm going to be using infrared light of wavelength somewhere around $700-800 \space \text{nm}$ and I need cheap materials that can be easily found/bought which are transparent to infrared light.

It has to have a solid structure so I can make different shapes which would help in my testing. If I missed some information, please let me know.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by transparent to?

Comment: Common salt, NaCl, is often used in IR work.

Comment: Look into polymethylmethacrylate (acrylic plastic, perspex or lucite). It's pretty transparent in the near infrared, and possibly easier to cut and shape than rock salt.

Comment: @TNTCookie, it has to be transparent to infrared light of wavelength 700 - 800 nm

Comment: @PM2Ring, it has to be something rigid, like say cardboard or wood, etc

Comment: @PhilipWood, could you check out this link and see if this would do the job: https://www.amazon.in/Bigmall-Acrylic-Sheet-Transparent-Plexiglass/dp/B077CJ9741?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=_k_EAIaIQobChMIzsSnkpK84wIVkCQrCh0whADxEAYYAyABEgLdzPD_BwE_k_&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzsSnkpK84wIVkCQrCh0whADxEAYYAyABEgLdzPD_BwE

Comment: I don't know enough about 'the job' to give an opinion. These acrylic sheets appear to be only 2 mm thick, so that limits you on the shapes you can make. The customer reviews aren't that good either. I'd have thought that you'd be better trying to get hold of a cheap off-cut to test before you spend a lot of money.

Comment: @PhilipWood ok got it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The region 700-800 nm is in the near infrared. Glass and transparent plastics (clear plastics) are fine there. You can test with the remote control of your TV.

Comment: Cool, I'll give glass a shot. Any constraint on thickness? By transparent plastic, you mean any plastic? Like there are certain kinds of plastics with thickness and composition right?

Comment: @Danush Many plastics are opaque in the visible. If they are not transparent in the red they are not likely to be transparent in the near-IR. Just test ordinary packaging, kitchenware, etc with the remote (typically 940 nm). For glass (window-pane quality), anything under 10 cm should work fine (thicker glass is often greenish).

Comment: cool thanks :)
Just one last question; would toughened glass under 10cm also work?

Comment: @Danush I just checked my remote with the heaviest piece of glass that I have right here (about 5 cm), and that worked. As I had expected; there is no reason why it should not.