# Need an IR transmitting plastic that is white in color and partially opaque to visible light?

Tags: optics, optical-materials

I need an IR transmitting plastic material (85% or better) that is white in color, but partially opaque to visible light. Does anyone know of such a substance?

Comment: Similar question: [What plastic-like materials allow IR to pass through them?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407900/what-plastic-like-materials-allow-ir-to-pass-through-them)

Comment: https://refractiveindex.info/

Comment: Do you have an idea of the wavelength ranges you want more precisely?

Comment: I have no expert knowledge of plastics or optics, but what do you mean by "transmit?" I.e., do you need a camera to be able to _see_ through it? or would it be enough for a photo transistor to be able to sense the presence of light on the other side of it? I'm skeptical about you finding a material that is clear at near IR wavelengths, but which also _diffusely_ reflects a broad band of visible light (i.e., "looks white"). Maybe some high-tech something with nanoparticles...

Comment: @SolomonSlow, if "IR" means 850 nm probably not. If it means 10 um, I imagine  you can add some scattering features at a small enough size not to affect the IR much, but to scatter visible light nicely.

Comment: @Solomon Slow Are you speaking of whether it's transparent or translucent?

Comment: @user47014, Yes.